# Yahoo BOSS Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory

Tags: java, yahoo-boss-api

I am trying to run [this Java example](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#) but I am receiving the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the CLASSPATH variable in your system to include the current directory or the location of your class

Answer (score 1):

```
NoClassDefFoundError
```

It can't find the class. Have you imported the required libraries and included it in your classpath?